# Search for not exact match and return value stored in column next to searched value if found

Tags: excel, vba, search, excel-formula, vlookup

I have one spreadsheet with Regions and region codes like:

```
  LocationCode       Location
     A001             Albania
     A003             Algeria
```

and so on.

Second spreadsheet contains lots of different information like:

```
UserID     Name   So on
A0010344   Mike
A0010345   Peter
```

I need to insert location to the second spreadsheet if `LocationCode` is found in `UserID`

So the output will look like:

```
UserID     Name   Location So on
A0010344   Mike    Albania
A0010345   Peter   Albania
A0038585   Tom     Algeria
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,4),Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```